# Using C# to transform a list of named classes into children of an XML element?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Given the following chunk of XML:

```
<stuff>
  <items>
    <thing1>stuff</thing1>
    <thing1>blah</thing1>
    <thing2>meh ..</thing2>
    <thing1>again</thing1>
  </items>
</stuff>
```

and assuming that I have classes like this:

```
public class thing1 { //handle members of the XML here no sweat }
public class thing2 { //handle members of the XML here no sweat }

public class stuff { public ListOfStuff items { get; set; } }
```

How do I define `ListOfStuff` so it works?

---

As an aside, it seems like this is the reduced problem that I'm trying to figure out, because I've got serialization working fine for "stuff" and for things one and two, it's finding a way to put lots of different types of thing1 and thing2 (of which I really have about 30 items to serialize into the XML like that, depending on the message). I'm pretty sure I've seen it done before, and that it looks like this:

```
[SomeAttribute(typeof(thing1))]
[SomeAttribute(typeof(thing2))]
public class ListOfStuff {
}
```

But I don't know ***precisely*** what that looks like, and that's what I'm trying to figure out. So, crappy title, crappy question, vaguely familiar, yes?

Comment: Are you looking for the KnownTypeAttribute? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574983.aspx

Comment: @Kassem is there one that also works for the Xml Serialization and not DCS?

Comment: @Kassem - Good thought, but I think the KnownTypeAttribute is useful for dealing with polymorphism (identifying known types that derive from a base type), but it doesn't have an effect on this case.

Comment: You're probably right. But the way I see it, since all of them are children of the `items` node, it makes sense to have all of them derive from an `ItemBase` class or something like that.

Comment: Sorry guys, right as I was getting ready to test the two approaches, I got told "why didn't you work on that lower priority ticket I told you to ignore?" so I will get back to you tomorrow midmorning central.

Comment: @Kassem - sorry, I was giving it a try with DataContractSerializer and KnownTypeAttribute and was not having any success, so I was thinking that it didn't work. In fact, that approach can work, but DataContractSerializer seems to want the XML tags to be structured as `<ItemBase xsi:type="thing1">` rather than `<thing1>`. I also had issues with the datatype of the items property being defined as `ListOfStuff`, but got it to work by changing it to `ItemBase[]`.

Comment: Update: got it to work with the items property as `ListOfStuff`; just had to make sure that I had DataContract / DataMember / CollectionDataContract attributes applied with the proper namespace specified. Using a ContractNamespace attribute also worked.

Comment: ListOfStuff, for reference, was to indicate that it was a list, and not a single entity. I rather expected to end up with an [] instead of a List<> on account of that's how the XML Serializer tends to like it. Doesn't bother me on that one. Glad you got it to work with the DCS.

Comment: Ahhh crap, can I get you two to look at this in a different light for me? I'm not supposed to have the items node in there, but everything else here is perfect...

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2354186#2354186 when I have time to think up how the Q should be posed, I shall ask it afresh, to ensure that points are awarded where due.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using what is referred to as "XML Serialization" (i.e. the XmlSerializer class in the System.Xml.Serialization namespace).

Put these attributes on your `items` property:

```
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(thing1))]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(thing2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer using the `DataContractSerializer` and the `KnownTypeAttribute` works fine. But in your case, and since you're using `XmlSerializer`, you can try using `XmlIncludeAttribute`

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just parse the xml and keep creating objects using reflection (i.e. Activator.CreateInstance method) and put it inside a ListOfStuff which holds a list of stuff objects which inturn holds List of things, assuming that thing1 n thing2 derive from things class.. getting it?

Comment: Because I'm using the C# XmlSerialization stuff natively, and not parsing the XML myself. Anyone parsing the XML themselves is asking for trouble, in my experience.